Controlling Velemx motors with Python
I have a velmex motor that moves vertically that I am attempting to control with Python. I was able to write a script that can move it up and down a desired number of steps. I would like to write a function that moves the velmex motor to the same position every time. From there I can use it to go to desired positions consistently. The current code does not set a reference point.
import serial
import time

class VelmexMotorController:
    def __init__(self, com_port, axis=1, home_position=0, target_start_position=-9000, baudrate=9600, timeout=5, max_step=2000):
        self.com_port = com_port
        self.axis = axis  # Specify the axis (1 by default)
        self.baudrate = baudrate
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.home_position = home_position  # Define the home position (e.g., 0 steps)
        self.target_start_position = target_start_position  # Define the desired starting position
        self.current_position = 0  # Track the current position of the motor
        self.ser = None  # Serial object, initialized later
        self.max_step = max_step  # Max steps per command to prevent overload

    def connect(self):
        """Initialize and open the serial port."""
        self.ser = serial.Serial()
        self.ser.port = self.com_port
        self.ser.baudrate = self.baudrate
        self.ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
        self.ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
        self.ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
        self.ser.timeout = self.timeout
        self.ser.xonxoff = False
        self.ser.rtscts = False
        self.ser.dsrdtr = False
        self.ser.writeTimeout = 2

        try:
            self.ser.open()  # Attempt to open the serial port
            print(f"Serial port {self.ser.port} opened successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error opening serial port: {e}")
            return False
        return True

    def disconnect(self):
        """Close the serial port."""
        if self.ser and self.ser.isOpen():
            self.ser.close()
            print(f"Serial port {self.ser.port} closed.")

    def move(self, steps, delay=1):
        """Move the motor a specified number of steps on the specified axis, with delay."""
        if not self.ser or not self.ser.isOpen():
            print("Serial port not open.")
            return

        remaining_steps = abs(steps)
        direction = 1 if steps > 0 else -1  # Determine direction of movement
        
        while remaining_steps > 0:
            move_steps = min(remaining_steps, self.max_step)  # Limit each move to max_step steps
            move_steps *= direction  # Apply direction
            
            try:
                # Flush input and output buffers
                self.ser.flushInput()
                self.ser.flushOutput()

                # Send command to move the motor on the specified axis
                command = f"F,C,I{self.axis}M{move_steps},R\r\n".encode('utf-8')
                self.ser.write(command)

                time.sleep(delay)  # Wait for the motor to complete the movement
                self.current_position += move_steps  # Update the current position
                print(f"Moved {move_steps} steps on axis {self.axis}. Current position: {self.current_position}")

            except Exception as e1:
                print(f"Error communicating: {e1}")
                break
            
            remaining_steps -= abs(move_steps)  # Reduce the remaining steps to move

    def go_home(self, delay=5):
        """Move the motor back to the home position on the specified axis."""
        steps_to_home = -self.current_position  # Steps to return to home (reverse of current position)
        self.move(steps_to_home, delay)
        print(f"Motor on axis {self.axis} returned to home position.")
        self.current_position = self.home_position  # Reset the current position to home

    def read_current_position(self):
        """Read the current position of the motor from the hardware."""
        # Replace with the actual command to read the position
        try:
            command = f"F,C,I{self.axis}PR\r\n".encode('utf-8')  # Replace with correct read command
            self.ser.write(command)
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Wait for response

            response = self.ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()  # Read response
            self.current_position = int(response)  # Assuming response is the current position
            print(f"Current position read: {self.current_position}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading current position: {e}")

    def initialize(self):
        """Move to home position initially and then to the target start position."""
        print(f"Homing the motor on axis {self.axis}...")
        self.go_home()  # Start by going to the home position
        
        # Read the current position after homing
        self.read_current_position()

        # Calculate the steps needed to reach the target start position
        steps_to_start = self.target_start_position - self.current_position
        print(f"Moving to target start position: {self.target_start_position} from current position: {self.current_position}...")
        self.move(steps_to_start)  # Move to the target start position
        print(f"Motor on axis {self.axis} is now at the starting position: {self.current_position}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize motor controller for axis 2
    motor = VelmexMotorController(com_port="COM3", axis=2)
    
    # Connect to the motor
    if motor.connect():
        motor.initialize()  # Home the motor initially and move to target start position
        
        # Example movement
        # motor.move(-6000, delay=1)  # Move motor -60000 steps on axis 2, with 1 second delay between chunks
        
        # Disconnect after operations
        motor.disconnect()
 

This code does not seem to be homing and returns inaccurate reference points. Output from console:
Serial port COM3 opened successfully.
Homing the motor on axis 2...
Motor on axis 2 returned to home position.
Error reading current position: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '?^'
Moving to target start position: -9000 from current position: 0...
Moved -2000 steps on axis 2. Current position: -2000
Moved -2000 steps on axis 2. Current position: -4000
Moved -2000 steps on axis 2. Current position: -6000
Moved -2000 steps on axis 2. Current position: -8000
Moved -1000 steps on axis 2. Current position: -9000
Motor on axis 2 is now at the starting position: -9000
Serial port COM3 closed.

I may be interpreting the vxm commands incorrectly?
https://velmex.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/VXM-Command-Summary-Rev-B-814.pdf
